# Lista con flex en footer para que se ajuste segun tamaño

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tengo en el footer de mi pagina una lista que necesito que se ajuste según el tamaño del ancho del dispositivo. Para que se vea todo el listado le puse un estilo flex al footer para que los parrafos de los elementos 'li' se pusieran en columna en caso que el ancho fuera mas pequeño que el contenido. El caso es que no funciona para navegador móvil de Google y en Opera por ejemplo si que va.

Tengo el siguiente código en css:

```
footer ul {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

y en HTML:

```
<footer>
  <nav id="navFooter">
     <ul>
       <li>©2018 Pagina web</li>
       <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.myweb.es/privacidad" accesskey="8"> Condiciones de uso y Política de privacidad</a></li>
       <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.myweb.es/cookies" accesskey="8"> Política de cookies</a></li>
       <li><a target="_new" href="https://www.myweb.es/lopd" accesskey="9">LOPD</a></li>
     </ul>
   </nav>
</footer>
```

Comment: prueba usando flex-direction:column

Comment: Añadi el flex-direction:column tal como me comentastes y funciono perfecto ! Gracias !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

esto seria suficiente

```
footer ul {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: flex-end;
flex-direction:column;
}
```

Comment: Correcto! Gracias !